# AngularJS + Rule Engine

Tags: angularjs, drools, rule-engine, drools-guvnor

Is there any way to integrate Rule Engine (or Rule Engine concept to apply Business Rules) with AngularJS application?

I have heard about Drools. Is there any API provided by Drools which can be used in Angular Project?

My requirement is any input given by the user should first go to match the applicable rules, then it should pass to the angular-controller. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to write a REST (or other HTTP-based) service to wrap your Drools rules. That way a client-side JavaScript framework such as Angular JS can call your REST operations.

The following is an example of an Angular JS client-side application integrating with Drools on the server: https://github.com/gratiartis/qzr

Although I should warn you that it's a work in progress, so please don't complain about lack of features or documentation. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can also try IBM ODM (Operational Decision Manager), available on-premise or in IBM Cloud Bluemix.

http://bluemixtips.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/rules-on-bluemix.html
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-hotel-rules-app/index.html (NodeJS sample)

Cheers

--Yves
@ylecleach

Answer (score 1):

For drools, there are two possibilities:

First solution, as mentioned by Steve, is to write your own REST service to wrap drools engine.
The other solution is to use Drools Camel Server, which provides REST interface out of the box.
In contrary to other drools' document, the document of Camel server is a bit too short.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JavaScript client](http://www.flexrule.com/archives/javascript-decision-as-a-service/) to talk to a decision-as-a-service platform. Which the business rule/decision server hosts all your related business rules and make them available as a REST API interface. Then you can execute, manage and monitor those business rules via REST API interface.